# jQuery - Hover lots of times breaks javascript?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a simple bit of code, when the user hovers over an image on a slideshow, the associated text fades in over the image. However if the user hovers back and forth a few times the effect just stops working?

```
$('div.slideshowImage').hover(function() {
$('div.slideshowImageText').stop().fadeIn('500');
},
function() {
$('div.slideshowImageText').fadeOut('500');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clear the queue as well, like this:

```
$('div.slideshowImage').hover(function() {
  $('div.slideshowImageText').stop(true).fadeIn('500');
}, function() {
  $('div.slideshowImageText').fadeOut('500');
});
```

The first parameter of [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) tells it whether to clear the queue or not...currently you're stopping the animation, but repeated hover-outs will queue up competing animations screwing with your fades...when you don't want the queue to execute later, clear it out, otherwise it'll interfere like it does here.

Comment: Thanks. That still dosn't seem to solve it though. If you hover over the image of the dog quickly more than 3 times it just stops working and you have to refresh the page to get it back http://test.clothesaid.co.uk/news/detail/vulputate-egestas-tellus-ultricies

Comment: @Yammi - Ah you have *another* issue, where your fade value is being stored from the previous fadeout not completing, use `.animate()` for that, like this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5Mp2v/

Comment: That's great! So having the .unbind() will remove what had been attributed to that event in the first instance?

Comment: @Yammi - oh woops, remove that `.unbind()` that was me in the console removing your handler in the page...there's no need for it when *replacing* your code as you'll do :)